# WebRequest converting URL to Encoded in Xamarin (MonoTouch)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, httpwebrequest

I am working on a API based App in Xamarin using HttpWebRequest class. I have to send request to URL

```
http://example.com/APIRequest/Request?Parts=33333|N|2014|ABCD
```

But when I see this request in Fiddler it shows me URL like

```
http://example.com/APIRequest/Request?Parts=33333%7CN%7C2014%7CABCD
```

Now the problem is this encoded URL is not getting understood by server and its returning errors, which is beyond my control.

Earlier in .NET2.0 C# Application I was using

```
Uri url = new Uri(rawurl, true);
```

But the second parameter has been deprecated in .NET 4.0 MonoTouch available on Xamarin so its giving error or simply not doing anything.

I have  tried all possible ways like UrlDecode, htmldecode, double decode or even Java UrlDecode but nothing has worked and always shows encoded URL in Fiddler.

Please suggest how to overcome this problem or any alternate to new Uri(url-string, true) the old function.

### UPDATE:

After spending hours n hours probably I have found the culprit. The problem is

When I use "new Uri(url, true)", it sends unescaped URL containing | (pipe) to WebRequest.Create but if I remove "true" it sends encoded URL, which produces result but unfortunately server doesn't understand, so I get error.

```
Uri ourUri = new Uri(url, true);
myHttpWebResponse1 = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

But it may be a bug that request.GetResponse() Stops working without throwing any exception and process hangs if I use | (pipe) in URL.

Any possible solution to that?

My complete function is given below (modified with hardcoded URL)

```
public static string getURLCustom(string GETurl, string GETreferal)
{
    GETurl = "http://example.com/?req=111111|wwww|N|2014|asdwer4";
    GETreferal = "";
    Uri ourUri = new Uri(GETurl.Trim(), true);
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)(WebRequest.Create(ourUri));
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/4.0 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)";
    request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
    request.KeepAlive = true;
    request.CookieContainer = loginCookie; //stored after login
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.Referer = GETreferal;
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse1 = default(HttpWebResponse);
    myHttpWebResponse1 = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    StreamReader postreqreader1 = new StreamReader(myHttpWebResponse1.GetResponseStream());
    return postreqreader1.ReadToEnd();
}
```

And yes this code works perfectly in .NET 2.0 Windows Application but not on Xamarin Mono-Touch App.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the server you are connecting to does not support internationalized resource identifier (IRI).

IRI is enabled by default since mono 3.10. [mono 3.10 release notes](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/3.10.0/)

You can disable it on your client application by doing:

```
FieldInfo iriParsingField = typeof (Uri).GetField ("s_IriParsing",
    BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
if (iriParsingField != null)
    iriParsingField.SetValue (null, false);
```

You can also disable IRI parsing by setting the environment variable MONO_URI_IRIPARSING to false.